# Unable to get the correct value for the arrow keys

Tags: c++

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int startMenu(vector<string> arr, int pos){

    /* Keyboard

    up    : char(72)
    down  : char(80)
    left  : char(75)
    right : char(77)

    */

    char userChar;

refresh:

    system("cls");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        if (i == pos){
            cout << "> " << arr[i] << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "  " << arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    userChar = _getch();

    switch (userChar){
    case 0:
    case 0xE0:
        break;
    case 72:
    case 75:
        --pos;
        break;
    case 80:
    case 77:
        ++pos;
        break;
    case 13:
        return pos;
    default:
        break;
    }

    cout << pos << endl;

    if (pos >= arr.size()){
        pos = 0;
    }

    if (pos == -1){
        pos = arr.size() - 1;
        cout << "arr.size() - 1 = " << arr.size() - 1 << endl;
    }

    goto refresh;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> arr;
    arr.push_back("Jamie");
    arr.push_back("Alex");

    startMenu(arr, 0);
}
```

When `pos` is 0 and I pressed up / left key, `pos` should be changed to be 1 (because `arr.size() - 1`), however `pos` is read as 0 (because arrow keys return 'special' values).

How can I read `-1` instead of `0` after pressing left / up arrow keys when pos is 0?

Comment: First you said that when you press up/left the pos should be 1 and then at the end you actually want to be -1. Is this a mistake? Can you be more clearly on what you really want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably saw a signed/unsigned mismatch warning on this line when you compiled:

```
if (pos >= arr.size())
```

What that warning is telling you is that one of the values in the expression, in this case arr.size() is unsigned and the other, pos is signed.  This means that in order to compare them, pos will be converted to an unsigned value first.  That means that instead of -1 it will be a very large value, certainly larger than the number of lines in the menu, the comparison will be true and pos will be set to 0.

The smallest change to fix that would be to change the line to this:

```
if(pos >= static_cast<int>(arr.size()))
```

This forces arr.size() to be the same type as pos so the values can be compared directly and solves your problem.  It also gets rid of the warning.

You should see some other warnings as well, another signed/unsigned mismatch in the for loop that displays the menu and a conversion from int to char warning for _getch() since it returns an int and you are storing it in a char.  Neither should cause a problem in this program, but you should always check and correct them to avoid issues.

Another potential issue is that discarding the extended key value, 0 or 0xE0 means you have no way to tell if the key is really an arrow key or the actual key with the ASCII value you are checking for.  As an example, typing H would also return 72 from _getch().

I won't try and talk you out of goto, but in my opinion you should avoid it.